# Examples of Combo box controls for the Web

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for examples of Combo box controls relying on jquery, or just javascript and CSS. The control would allow the user to slect from a drop down list, or simply type a custom value.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Answer (score 2):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jEC

sample:  http://stuff.rajchel.pl/jec/demos/